# Elegir imagen diferente "IMAGELIST" cada que imprima un pdf dependiendo de un texbox

Tags: itextsharp

Tengo este código el cual quisiera que de texempresa.text = "XXXXempre" eligiera la imagen dependiendo la empresa, alguien sabe el error?

Cabe mencionar que si imprime los folios al elegir diferente empresa, tengo el problema con las imágenes, carga las 2 y no elije.

```
Dim IMG As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\logo.png")
       Dim IMG2 As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\Logo2.png")

       e.Graphics.DrawImage(pblogo.Image, 490, 230)
       e.Graphics.DrawImage(pblogo2.Image, 490, 230)

       If textempresa.Text = "EMPRESA1" Then
           textfoli.Text = "EMPRESA FOLIO-"
           pblogo.Image = ImageList1.Images(1)

       Else textempresa.Text = "EMPRESA2"
           textfoli.Text = "EMPRESA 2 FOLIO-"
           pblogo2.Image = ImageList1.Images(2)
       End If
```

Answer (score 0):

si a alguien le pasa lo solucione quitando esta linea

`introducir el código aquí`e.Graphics.DrawImage(pblogo2.Image, 490, 230)

y solo declarando pblogo.